# Tree of template class where chilldren are std::array of std::unique_ptr

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, unique-ptr

I am in the following situation:

```
template<size_t Level>
class Node
{
public:

    Node()
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < children.size(); i++)
            children[i].reset(new Node<Level - 1>());
    }

    array<unique_ptr<Node<Level - 1>>, 4> children;
};


template<>
class Node<0>
{
};

...

Node<2> root;
```

I need to create a tree of nodes, where each node, but the last (level = 0), has 4 children. I thought to store the children in a `std:array` of `std::unique_ptr`.

Is my solution right or am I doing somenthing wrong and there is a smarter way to achieve this result?

Comment: It seems that you can directly use `std::array<Node<Level - 1>, 4>`.

Comment: @Jarod42 only in theory, I cannot have a too deep level without using pointers.

Comment: If this really is what you want to achieve, that's ok. You may possibly consider changing the `std::array<Node,4>` into `std::tuple<Node,Node,Node,Node>`, if you are going to use compile-time (not runtime) indexing of any of these 4 children.

Comment: @Ethouris it appears the OP may take this beyond what would normally fit into automatic storage, thus the reason `std::unique_ptr` is used. The `std::array<Node,4>` was in a comment; not the question. A tree 10 levels deep, for example, without pointers, will consume some 27MB of automatic storage, considerably larger than most implementations set aside.

Comment: I meant `std::array<Type,4>`, just used `Node` because I was tricked by the example code :)/

Comment: @Ethouris A homogeneous `std::tuple` really offers little advantage over a `std::array`, which can be used with `std::get` etc. as well.

Comment: in your approach every Node would have a different type, being an instantiation of a different template. Your code size will grow a lot for nothing, and getting rid of a Node and shifting the others up, will result in recreating all the children nodes. 
Get rid of the template, you don't need it here. 
Also, you don't need to specifically initialize the nodes in the constructor, just use uniform initialization! 
array<unique_ptr<Node>, 4> children = { };

Comment: @T.C.: The only advantage of get<N>(x) over x[N] is that the first one does always compile-time access (practically: it will report error if you tried to access it using runtime index value), which is what I have suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the value of having a template here. The tree is fixed and limited size, you can make it a value type.

E.g. a 4-level tree with leaf nodes containing a value of type `V`:

```
namespace Tree {

    template <typename V>
    struct Root {

        struct Tier1 {
            struct Tier2 {
            struct Tier3 {
            struct Leaf { V value; };

            std::array<Leaf, 4> children;
            };
            std::array<Tier3, 4> children;
            };
            std::array<Tier2, 4> children;
        };

        std::array<Tier1, 4> children;
    };
}
```

Of course, if the nodes can be optional at all levels, use `boost::optional<>`:

```
std::array<optional<Leaf>, 4> children; };
std::array<optional<Tier3>, 4> children; };
std::array<optional<Tier2>, 4> children; };
std::array<optional<Tier1>, 4> children;
```

If you don't have boost, you could use `unique_ptr` as a poor-man's optional there (but this has a lot of impact on memory layout).

## One more time, with <strike>feeling</strike> templates:

You can express the same with templates:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cf1f3b71bb301d2e)</kbd>**

```
#include <array>
#include <boost/optional.hpp>

namespace Tree {

    using boost::optional;

    template <typename LeafValue, int level> struct Node;

    template <typename LeafValue> struct Node<LeafValue, 3> {
        LeafValue value;
    };

    template <typename LeafValue, int level> struct Node {
        std::array<optional<Node<LeafValue, level+1> >, 4> children;
    };

    template <typename LeafValue> using Root = Node<LeafValue, 0>;
}


int main() 
{
    Tree::Root<int> a = {
    };
}
```

Comment: With a compiler with decent ICF in the linker, code size would only grow in the cases where there is an actual difference.  Admittedly most compilers lack ICF support (identical comdat folding), except MSVC and the Gold linker for gcc (last I checked).

Comment: @Yakk did I miss a comment that talked about code/binary size?

Comment: I thought I read a bit about "duplicating methods" or somesuch in your answer.  I cannot see it in edit history, so maybe I hallucinated.

Comment: @Yakk I'm just sceptical of templates for templates. Note how I did, however, add the type argument for `LeafValue`. Because that one does make sense to me